# Open multiple pickle files from Jupyter notebook folder doesn't work

Tags: python, server, jupyter-notebook, pickle, concatenation

I'm using jupyter notebook on a server (the folders are not on my computer). I have folder with 30 dataframes pickled that have exactly the same columns. They are all saved in the next path:

> Reut/folder_no_one/here_the_files_located

I want to open them all and to concat them.
I know I could do something like this:

```
df1=pd.read_pickle('table1')
df2=pd.read_pickle('table2')
df3=pd.read_pickle('table3')
...
#and then concat
```

but i'm sure there is better and smarters way to do so.
I have tried to open all the files and save them seperatly as following:

```
num=list(range(1, 33)) #number of tables I have in the folder
path_to_files=r'Reut/here_the_files_located'
Path=r'Reut/folder_no_one/here_the_files_located'

{f"df{num}" : pd.read_pickle(file) for num, file in enumerate(Path(path_to_files).glob('*.pickle'))}
```

but I get error with this:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 {f"df{num}" : pd.read_pickle(file) for num, file in enumerate(Path(path_to_files).glob('*.pickle'))}
>
> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

I have tried to play and o put different version of the path, also not to put path (because my notebook is where those files are) but I keep getting the same error.

***it's important to mention that when I can open those files without specifiying the path when the notebook is inside that folder as well.**

****My end goal is to open and concat all those tables as one big table automatically.****

edit: I have also tried this:

```
path = r'file_name/file_location_with_all_pickles'
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.pkl")

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_pickle(filename)
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

and also

```
path_to_files = r'file_name/file_location_with_all_pickles'
tables = []
for table in pathlib.Path(path_to_files).glob("*.pkl"):
    print(table)
    tables.append(pd.read_pickle(table))
```

but both cases I get error

> ValueError: No objects to concatenate
> when I try to concat. also when I tell it to print the filename/table it does nothing. also if inside the loop I try to print just ordinary string (like print('hello'), nothing happens.
> it seems like there is problem with the path but when I open one specific pickle like this:

```
pd.read_pickle(r'file_name/file_location_with_all_pickles/specific_table.pkl')
```

it opens.

'update:

this worked for me inthe end:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'folder' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.pkl")

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_pickle(filename)
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

from here ([Open multiple pickle files from Jupyter notebook folder doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64192388/open-multiple-pickle-files-from-jupyter-notebook-folder-doesnt-work))

Comment: `Path` is a string in your exemple, and you are calling `Path(` so the error makes sense. May be you are overriding another function.

Comment: anyway something like `pd.concatenate([pd.read_pickle(file) for file in os.listdir(your_files_path)])` should work but in terms of memory you're not doing anything different than one by one loading your files.

Comment: By the way why do you use regex `r'` flag in your strings ?

Comment: @AlexisBenichoux the `r` prefix is not regex related. It means the string is a raw string. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```py
path_to_files = r'Reut/here_the_files_located'
df = pd.concat([pd.read_pickle(f'{path_to_files}/table{num}.pickle') for num in range(1, 33)])
```

This is equivalent to:

```py
path_to_files = r'Reut/here_the_files_located'
tables = []
for num in range(1, 33):
    filename = f'{path_to_files}/table{num}.pickle'
    print(filename)
    tables.append(pd.read_pickle(filename))

df = pd.concat(tables)
```

Output:

```
Reut/here_the_files_located/table1.pickle
Reut/here_the_files_located/table2.pickle
Reut/here_the_files_located/table3.pickle
Reut/here_the_files_located/table4.pickle
Reut/here_the_files_located/table5.pickle
Reut/here_the_files_located/table6.pickle
Reut/here_the_files_located/table7.pickle
Reut/here_the_files_located/table8.pickle
Reut/here_the_files_located/table9.pickle
Reut/here_the_files_located/table10.pickle
Reut/here_the_files_located/table11.pickle
Reut/here_the_files_located/table12.pickle
Reut/here_the_files_located/table13.pickle
Reut/here_the_files_located/table14.pickle
Reut/here_the_files_located/table15.pickle
Reut/here_the_files_located/table16.pickle
Reut/here_the_files_located/table17.pickle
Reut/here_the_files_located/table18.pickle
Reut/here_the_files_located/table19.pickle
Reut/here_the_files_located/table20.pickle
Reut/here_the_files_located/table21.pickle
Reut/here_the_files_located/table22.pickle
Reut/here_the_files_located/table23.pickle
Reut/here_the_files_located/table24.pickle
Reut/here_the_files_located/table25.pickle
Reut/here_the_files_located/table26.pickle
Reut/here_the_files_located/table27.pickle
Reut/here_the_files_located/table28.pickle
Reut/here_the_files_located/table29.pickle
Reut/here_the_files_located/table30.pickle
Reut/here_the_files_located/table31.pickle
Reut/here_the_files_located/table32.pickle
```

A few comments about your code:

```py
num=list(range(1, 33)) #number of tables I have in the folder
path_to_files=r'Reut/here_the_files_located'
Path=r'Reut/folder_no_one/here_the_files_located'

{f"df{num}" : pd.read_pickle(file) for num, file in enumerate(Path(path_to_files).glob('*.pickle'))}
```

```py
num=list(range(1, 33)) #number of tables I have in the folder
```

There is no need to create a `list` with `range`. Using `range` directly in a for loop or list/dictionary comprehension works perfectly.

```py
Path=r'Reut/folder_no_one/here_the_files_located'
```

I'm guessing that you have previously imported the `Path` class from `pathlib`. You need to choose another name for that variable if you want to call `Path` like normal. This is why you got the error `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`.

---

> is there nay way to use it if the tables names' are not the same? e.g if one was table1 and one is dataframe3, just to read them not depended on their name

Sure. Assuming the filenames for all your saved tables end with `.pickle`, you can use the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) method like you first tried. Don't forget to `import pathlib`.

```py
import pathlib
path_to_files = r'Reut/here_the_files_located'
tables = []
for table in pathlib.Path(path_to_files).glob("*.pickle"):
    tables.append(pd.read_pickle(table))

df = pd.concat(tables)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, is there nay way to use it if the tables names' are not the same? e.g if one was table1 and one is dataframe3, just to read them not depended on their name

Comment: I've updated my answer. There are multiple ways to do that. It's pretty simple if all the tables you want to load end in ".pickle".